# Fixing subtraction and division operations with "neutral starting point" in calculator - Python

Tags: python, calculator, division, subtraction

Yesterday I asked a question about the calculating function of a text calculator I am creating. I received a response suggesting I use the `operator` module for a Pythonic way of operating on *two or more* operands.

The calculator calculates using one function for all operations. A dictionary (`operatorsDict`), consisting of four entries, one for each operation, stores "presets" for each operation. When the function is executed, the presets for the chosen operation are loaded. One of those presets is the "neutral starting point". This is the function:

```
def Calculate():
    global result, operatorsDict  #result is the answer to the calculation and = 0 at this point
    opFunc, result = operatorsDict[operation] #loading presets from dictionary - 
    for operand in operandList:
        result = opFunc(result, operand)
```

In this setup, multiplication needs a NSP of 1: That way, instead of multiplying `result` (0) by each operand, which yields zero no matter what, it multiplies one and the operands together. An NSP is not needed for addition.

Subtraction and division, however, need NSP's. They both should have `operandList[0]` as their NSP, but that will cause the current system to stop working.

Is there any way I could modify the function to make it work for operations that need NSP's of the first operand such as subtraction and division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `operandList[0]` as the starting point if you wish, as long of course as `operandList` is not empty (up to you what you want to do when it **is** empty).

```
if not operandList:
    raise ValueError('Empty operand list')  # or whatever
result = operandList[0]
for operand in operandList[1:]
    result = opFunc(result, operand)
```

Comment: Suppose `operandList = [12, 4]` and `operation = '/'`. If the NSP was set to `operandList[0]`, the calculation would go like so: 1st iteration: `result = 12 / 12` 2nd iteration: `result = 1 / 4` and so the final result would be `0.25`, obviously incorrect.

Comment: @Jacob, as usual, you're **wrong** (very consistent track record!).  The loop is on the `[1:]` slice of the list, so there is never any `12/12` -- the first (and, here, only) division is `12/4`, returning 3.0, obviously **correct**.  Do you even **bother** to try the code in my answers, and just fail to notice they work fine, or can't you even have that modicum of common decency before arrogantly claiming my code is "obviously incorrect"?!

Comment: Ah, I did not see that in the code block you wrote. I did not copy the code you posted. Apologies. I wrote 'obviously incorrect' to mean it was obvious 12/4 did not equal 0.25, not to insult you. Ironically, you have been quite rude to me in my last question, acting as if I have no knowledge of anything at all..

Comment: It pains me to think that by accepting your answer, as I fairly must do so, I am supporting your arrogance and disrespect.

Comment: @Jacob, I fully expect you to withdraw this acceptance, just like you withdrew without no explanation nor justification your previous acceptance of my answer to your earlier question -- apparently it's just the kind of person you are -- just as you didn't upvote my fully correct answer.  What "disrespect"?!  You didn't *see* the code I wrote, you didn't *run* it, **yet** you still publicly claimed it's "obviously incorrect" on no basis whatsoever -- now **that**, **your** behavior!, is arrogance and disrespect.  I just called you out on several easily verifiable **facts**: you know, _reality_.

Comment: I did see your code, I just did not see the most important detail. I withdrew my acceptance of your answer on the last question because division and subtraction did not work properly when I tested them. I already explained why I said 'obviously incorrect' - not at all to insult you, but to say 12/4 is obviously not .025. I was very clear about that. Please do not pick on my personality. I am by no means intending to insult you, your advanced and superior knowledge, or your personality; I am only disappointed in the way you address me.